# SQLAlchemy not updating model, ignores all changed fields except the last modified one

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following model:

```py
class Model(db.Base):
    """Table for storing snapshots of Projects health."""
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    first_attribute = Column(Integer)
    second_attribute = Column(Integer)
    created_at = Column(DateTime)
```

I need to update an existing object's attributes. This is what it happens:

```py
ipdb> model = (
    db.session.query(Model)
    .filter(id=5908)
    .first()
)

ipdb> logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ipdb> model.first_attribute
1
ipdb> model.second_attribute
1
ipdb> model.first_attribute = object.some_value
ipdb> model.second_attribute = object.another_value
ipdb> model.created_at = get_utc_now()
ipdb> model.first_attribute
0
ipdb> model.second_attribute
0
ipdb> db.session.add(model)
ipdb> db.session.commit()
ipdb> model.first_attribute
1
ipdb> model.second_attribute
1
```

So, the model originally had a value, 1, which has been changed, to 0, and after committing it, it remains 1. So is the value in database.

Actually, the debug statement admits that it doesn't care about `first_attribute` nor `second_attribute`, and it only updates `created_at`:

```
2020-02-13 10:55:29,133 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - BEGIN (implicit)
2020-02-13 10:55:29,137 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - UPDATE my_table SET created_at=%(created_at)s WHERE my_table.id = %(id)s
2020-02-13 10:55:29,138 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - {'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 13, 9, 54, 9, 610208, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'id': 5908}
2020-02-13 10:55:29,345 - sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine - INFO - COMMIT
```

The fun fact is that the only updated field is the last modified one before adding the model to the session. I've swapped `model.created_at` and `model.first_attribute` value assignments, leaving this second one as the last before `db.session.add(model)`, and it does get updated (being this the only one updated, again).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], or in other words your model definition, and the code that produces `model` instance.

Comment: Not sure if you have the setting on, but all models should become invalid on commit and after the commit you need to reload them from the database?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa In normal operation SQLA does that automatically. Something else is at play here.

Comment: From the prompt it looks like the commands are being run in a debugger. That might or might not have something to do with the odd behaviour.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, it's also happening on production. I've also tried from the debugger to check it manually.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but the code in the question does not produce that behaviour for me. Maybe include exact versions of the involved libraries in case it's an actual bug or such.

Answer (score 1):

I could make this work using `db.session.merge(model)` instead of `db.session.add(model)`.

Looks like, for some reason I still don't really get, that `model` instance wasn't within the session scope. `merge` copies the state of the given instance to the one that it's within the session, based on the primary key attributes (you still need to commit the transaction to save the changes in the db).

SQLAlchemy documentation on this: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge

Comment: Missed the call to `add()` reading the question before. It should be redundant, given that the model object is the result of a query, in which case the object should already be a part of the session producing it. `db.session` in Flask-SQLAlchemy is a scoped session, so it serves *thread-local* sessions. That might be something to look into.